# Large Form submission in Chrome

Tags: jsp, networking

Does Google chrome breaks the large form (example in my case length 30000kb) before submission ? because when i analyse the network with network protocol analyser , IE doesn't break the large form , and submits the whole form as one request . but Google chrome break into 2 chunks and submits , and i get error because of this .

Comment: Please provide your code if possible, or a link to it

Comment: Its a normal jsp , which on button click , calls javascript which inturn submits the form

Comment: I get "encrypted alert" msg , when i analyse the request from wireshark